# Asp.net Chart Radar Line - None of the XAxis labels are showing

Tags: asp.net, charts, label, c#-2.0

Good afternoon,

I'm dynamically creating a number of Radar Charts with data from a database.

The data set looks like

```
X  | Y
--------
1    2
2    2
3    1
4    4
5    0
6    2
```

When the charts are show the Xaxis label is not visible
Can anyone recommend why this is occuring?

This is my code so far...

```
Chart aRadarChart = new Chart();

        aRadarChart.Width = Unit.Pixel(450);
        aRadarChart.DataSource = dt;

        // Add title 
        Title t = new Title(title, Docking.Top, new Font("Helvetica Neue", 12f,              FontStyle.Bold), ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#696969"));

        aRadarChart.Titles.Add(t);
        //aRadarChart.Titles.
        // Add a legend 
        Legend lgnd = new Legend();
        lgnd.Enabled = true;
        aRadarChart.Legends.Add(lgnd);

        //Important: add ChartArea, otherwise no graph will be shown
        ChartArea ca = new ChartArea("myChartArea");
        ca.AxisX.Interval = 1;
        ca.AxisX.TextOrientation = TextOrientation.Horizontal;
        aRadarChart.ChartAreas.Add(ca);

        ca.AxisY.Maximum = 4;

        string car = String.Empty;
        for (int i = 1; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            car = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName;

            aRadarChart.Series.Add(car);
            aRadarChart.Series[car].YValueMembers = car;
            aRadarChart.Series[car].XValueMember = dt.Columns[0].ColumnName.ToString();

            //Define here: what kind of Chart you want
            aRadarChart.Series[car].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Radar;
            aRadarChart.Series[car]["RadarDrawingStyle"] = "Line";
            aRadarChart.Series[car].BorderWidth = 3;

        }
             //binding data
            aRadarChart.DataBind();
            aRadarChart.ImageStorageMode =  ImageStorageMode.UseImageLocation;//.UseHttpHandler;

            //Add Chart to a PlaceHolder Control
            pnlMainContent.Controls.Add(aRadarChart);
```

Thanks
I have read about setting the interval to equal 1. But this is not doing the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why it was not working - In the select statement in sql I had to cast the x-axis column to type varchar. It was originally of type int.